# Issue with WYSIWYG Editor in magento2

Tags: magento, backend, editor, magento2, wysiwyg

Created a custom page from frontend when we toggle the show editor some code are automatically added and the response in backend is also different and for the page there is no issue on frontend we get a proper output as we excepted but on the backend page edit section some codes are duplicated we can verify this by click on show or hide editor button.

How can i fix this issue?

my current project working on 2.4.2-p2. I tried with the same code in default magento2.4.2-p2. it had this same issue.

this is the orginal file

```
<div>
    <h3 class="passages">LOREM IPSUM</h3>
    <p class="intro">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
    <ol class="intro">
        <li>What is a variations?</li>
            <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc..</p>
        <li>Why do we use Loreum?</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

After saving the page the code look like this

```
<div>
<h3 class="passages">LOREM IPSUM</h3>
<p class="intro">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<ol class="intro">
<ol class="intro">
<li>What is a variations?</li>
</ol>
</ol>
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc..</p>
<ol class="intro">
<li>Why do we use Loreum?</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

is there anyone faced this issue before.
without disable the WYSIWYG Editor how can we fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It because of we can't use the anyother tag in the in between the

.
If we use it will creates break in the code
for the above example we can use the below code

```
<div>
<h3 class="passages">LOREM IPSUM</h3>
<p class="intro">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>
<ol class="intro">
    <li>What is a variations?</li>
        There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc..
    <li>Why do we use Loreum?</li>
</ol>
```